# Can we apply cross validation bias correction to explanatory variable selection as well?

Tags: feature-selection, cross-validation

As shown in the paper below, several methods have been suggested for bias correction for cross validation. For example, Tibshirani-Tibshirani method and BBC-CV method. These are known to significantly reduce the amount of computation compared to nested cross validation.

https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2904
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-018-5714-4

I can apply these bias correction methods to hyperparameter searches, but can they be applied to explanatory variable searches (eg, genetic algorithms, sequential feature selection) as well?

Also, please let me know if there are any papers that bias corecction on explanatory variable selection.